# How to fetch Page ID in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am using this code to bring the content out of the page.

```
<?php
$page = get_page_by_title( 'page-title' );
$title = $page->post_title;
echo "<h3>" . $title . "</h3>";
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $page->post_content); 
echo $content;
?>
```

Now, i want to get the content and title by using page ID.

If any one has the answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`get_post()` function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post)

```
$myPost = get_post(17);
echo $myPost->post_title;
```

---

Per your comment:

> Is there any way i can avoid putting id in the direct code. eg. just
>   making a page and content from back-end it reflects in front-end. i am
>   making a **onepage website**. can it will be done by any kind of loop or
>   something like that.

I bolded that word because if this is the case there's a very simple solution, but there are many ways to reach it.

**Option 1:**

If you're familiar with the [WordPress Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) you'll know you can create a PHP paged called `front-page.php`. Then you can create 1 single page under `Pages`, once that's done you can go to `Settings -> Reading` and click the radio button which allows you to

> Set a static page (select below)

You can then select the page you created. This will automatically use the `front-page.php` template versus `page.php`.

**Option 2:**

You can copy your `page.php` template and rename it to use a pages slug. For instance, if I create a page called "Contact Us" WordPress will automatically make a slug that looks like `contact-us` which is part of the web URL to view the page. I can then copy `page.php` and rename it `page-contact-us.php` so when you view the "Contact Us" page, it will automatically use this page template.

**Option 3:**

Finally you can directly [create a Page Template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates) where you select it from a drop down in the Admin Panel when you create a new page. All you have to do is copy your `page.php` template file and call it whatever you want, something standard like `page_template-contact` or something of the sort. Then you can add this direct above your `get_header()` call:

```
/**
    Template Name: My Custom Page
**/
```

Comment: it worked for me, but is there any way i can avoid putting id in the direct code. eg. just making a page and content from back-end it reflects in front-end. i am making a onepage website. can it will be done by any kind of loop or something like that.

Comment: Please view my updated answer and refer to this link for [More information](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates). Good Luck!